# Dynamics 2011 ASPX Pages in IFRAME

Tags: .net, asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am in the process of upgrading a Dynamics 4.0 ISV solution to Dynamics 2011. The Dynamics 4.0 solution hosted content in the ISV directory within an IFRAME in Dynamics.

Since configuring this same behavior in Dynamics 2011, I now get the age old error:

```
System.Web.HttpException Error message: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
```

On any **second** request submitted by the page in the IFRAME. That is, if I click Submit once, it works. The second time I click Submit it busts and throws the above error.

Any ideas on the cause or on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

UPDATE: Even with the page directive EnableViewState="false", I still get this error on second post.

UPDATE 2: I've narrowed it down and I can see that it's an UpdatePanel that's triggering it. Once the first request is made using the UpdatePanel, the subsequent ones fail with the aforementioned. error....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISV directory has been [deprecated in CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309571.aspx).  There are a couple options when moving forward.

1. Convert the aspx assets over to web resources (html/javascript/silverlight).
2. Host a website independant of the CRM deployment and use Federated Services to authenticate inbetween.

Information is currently sparse on the second option.  Here are a couple links which may help:

[Implement Single Sign-on from an ASPX Web Page or IFRAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061.aspx)

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Claims Based Implementation Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9886ab96-3571-420f-83ad-246899482fb4)

Sorry for being so vague, but there is no silver bullet in this case.

Comment: I have an existing 4.0 solution here and abandoning our existing ASPX pages is not an option. The ISV directory is deprecated but still supported.

Comment: I totally agree, it should still work. The only other thing I can think of is attaching to the w3wp.exe process and see if you can get a more informative exception to throw than the vague one you are getting.

Comment: By attaching, I can see the error happens in between OnInit and OnLoad, but the stack trace is completely outside of my code.